# Mount root partition Arch

Tags: partition

I am a currently dual booting windows/ubuntu and I wanted to give arch a try and got caught up on a seemingly very basic question while reading through the installation guide.

In the installation guide for arch it explicitly states to "mount the root partition to /mnt directory", this has been confusing me. Shouldn't I mount the root partition to "/" ?? This is how I've always done it in other linux installs. Isn't the /mnt dir used for temporary devices? Or is there some differences in terminology I am missing?

I must be misunderstanding something very simple

Answer (score 4):

When installing a new linux system, from within an existing linux system, you need to maintain the separation of the two systems. The root of your existing system should (almost) always be `/` while the new linux system must exist somewhere, without wrestling for your existing system root.

The solution is to mount the target (new) file structure to a location within the existing linux system's root file structure.

To setup a new system manually (example):

Existing system file structure: `/dev/sda2` mounted at `/`

New system file structure: `/dev/sdb3` mounted at `/mnt`

This allows you to use the tools on the existing system to setup the file structure for the new system before using it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, If I am installing arch on a completely separate partition than Ubuntu, or on a virtual machine, I should not have to worry about the root of my existing system right?

Comment: You will. If you think about partitions the way windows handles them, each partition gets it's own drive letter, right? In a way the windows equivalent of linux's "root" or "/" is this otherwise empty place where the operating system links drive letters to partitions.
In linux, it is similar, but different. "root" must posses it's own partition, and within that file structure, other partitions can be mounted to various locations. So instead of "c:\" you have "/" and instead of "e:\" you have "/mnt/". There are NO drive letters, only mount points.